# Two minor typos in the API help

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

In http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help

`/users/{id}/answers` Gets answer summary **informatino** for the user with 'id'.

and in the **Returns** section of http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users/{id}/answers

```
"answer_comments_url": {
  "description": "a link to the method that returns comments on this question",
  "values": "string"
}
```

should presumably be:

```
"answer_comments_url": {
  "description": "a link to the method that returns comments on this answer",
  "values": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation has been fixed.